# Array List is not binding to thymeleaf table

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using thyme leaf. I have a table that displays dynamic records. I have tried 2 approaches to display the records, but the values are not binding.

**Approach - 1**

Using JQuery

```
$().ready(function () {
 getTableDetails();
});

function getTableDetails() {
    try {
        var ajaxCall;
        ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url: /getTableDetails
            type: 'GET',
            async:false,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        ajaxCall.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            $.each(data, function (i, p) {
                $('#details').append($('<tbody></tbody>').val(p).html(p));
            });
        });
        ajaxCall.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle failure cases
            alert(textStatus+errorThrown);
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

HTML File

```
 <table class="indi-data-table__table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="datatable-column-width125" role="columnheader">
                                    <div class="indi-data-table__column-heading">ID</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="datatable-column-width150" role="columnheader">
                                    <div class="indi-data-table__column-heading">NAME</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="details">
                            <tr th:each="row : ${tableDetailList}">
                                <td th:text="${row.id}"/>
                                <td th:text="${row.name}"/>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**Approach - 2**
Using Model getAttribute from Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTableDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<DataEntity> getTableDetails(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<DataEntity> tableDetailList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
           tableDetailList.addAll(repoCall);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("tableDetailList", tableDetailList);
        return tableDetailList;
    }
```

I have also tried

```
<tr th:each="row : ${tableDetailList}">
                                    <td th:text="${row.getId()}"/>
                                    <td th:text="${row.getName()}"/>
                                </tr>
```

But, none of them is actually binding the values, I am getting the response from the API.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!